# Что за свойства prototype и constructor?

Tags: javascript

Наблюдения я буду приводить на классе - конструкторе `Object`, так как отдельно о этих свойствах ничего не нашел. На [Современный учебник Javascript](https://learn.javascript.ru/) есть ООП в прототипном стиле, но конкретного определения нету.

Я пошел на сайты [Веб-документация MDN - Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/), [MSDN – сеть разработчиков Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru) на который прочел про данные свойства.

Начнем со свойства `constructor`.

1. [Object.prototype.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor): Возвращает ссылку на функцию
   `Object`, создавшую прототип экземпляра. Обратите внимание, что
   значение этого свойства является ссылкой на саму функцию, а не
   строкой, содержащей имя функции. Для примитивных значений, вроде 1,
   true или "test", значение доступно только для чтения.
2. [Свойство constructor (Object) (JavaScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c1hcx253(v=vs.94).aspx): Задает функцию, которая создает объект.
   **Комментарии**: Свойство constructor является членом прототипа каждого объекта, у которого есть прототип.  Это включает все встроенные объекты `JavaScript`, за исключением объектов `Global` и `Math`.  Свойство `constructor` содержит ссылку на функцию, которая создает экземпляры данного конкретного объекта.

В первом пункте я не понял, что они подразумевают под словосочетанием `...создавшую прототип экземпляра`.

Пример, на основе которого буду наглядно разбирать пункт 1.

```js
function Class() {}

var exemplar = new Class;
```

[image: содержимое объекта exemplar]

Объект(экземпляр) `exemplar` был создан на основе конструктора `Class`. Он унаследовал из своего конструктора свойство `prototype` в виде `__proto__` (я его затрону ниже), в котором находиться свойство constructor. Внутри этого свойство находиться ссылка на конструктор `Class`.

Вернусь к определению первого пункта: `Возвращает ссылку на функцию Object, создавшую прототип экземпляра`. Функция `Object`, а точнее конструктор создает объект(экземпляр) в первую очередь, а потом ему присваивается уже prototype конструктора в виде `__proto__`. Просто в определении ставят акцент на том, что конструктор создает только прототип экземпляра, а не экземпляр в частности.

Во втором пункте я не понял `...экземпляры данного конкретного объекта.`
Не пойму о каком объекте идет речь, так как Object является функцией - конструктором. Я знаю что конструкторы `Array`, `Object`, `Function` создают разные сущности, а точнее `Array` - массив, `Object` - объект, `Function` - функцию и все они являются объектами кроме примитивов, но только если они не созданы через свои конструкторы `Number`, `String` и тд.
P.S: `Свойство constructor содержит ссылку на функцию, которая создает экземпляры данного конкретного объекта`. Если это определение писалась на основе какого - то объекта, то вроде все понятно. К примеру есть объект `exemplar` из примера выше и его класс `Class`, а теперь разбираем определение в контексте этого экземпляра: `Свойство constructor(exemplar.__proto__.constructor) содержит ссылку на функцию(Class), которая создает экземпляры данного конкретного объекта(exemplar)`

Свойство `prototype`.

1. [Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype): Свойство `Object.prototype` представляет объект прототипа `Object`.
2. [Свойство prototype (Object) (JavaScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f5s9ycex(v=vs.94).aspx): Возвращает ссылку на прототип класса объектов. **Комментарии**: Свойство prototype используется для предоставления базового набора функциональных возможностей классу объектов.  Новые экземпляры объекта наследуют поведение прототипа, присвоенного этому объекту.

В первом пункте словосочетание: `...представляет объект прототипа Object` мне не понятно. В моем понимаю это должно звучать как: Свойство `Object.prototype` предназначено для предоставления базового функционала экземплярам класса `Object`.

Во втором пункте мне не понятна формулировка: `...прототип класса объектов`. По моему она должна звучать как: Возвращает ссылку на прототип экземпляров класса `Object`. Так же мне не понятно словосочетание `...классу объектов`. Уместней было перефразировать в: `Свойство prototype используется для предоставления базового набора функциональных возможностей экземплярам конкретного класса`.

Итог.

- Свойство `prototype` предназначено для предоставления базового функционала экземплярам класса. Оно используется в функциях - конструкторах(классах) по причине того, что при вызове конструктора через оператор `new`, экземпляр унаследует свойство `prototype` в виде свойства `__proto__` которое является прототипом. Это сделано для того, что бы все экземпляры которые могут отличаться от друг друга, могли иметь общие свойства, которые характерны этому классу.
- Свойство `constructor` является членом свойства `prototype` (`prototype.constructor`). В нем находиться ссылка на класс, который создает экземпляры. К примеру у нас есть функция - конструктор(класс) `Class` и его экземпляр `exemplar`, который унаследовал свойство `prototype` в виде `__proto__`. Внутри прототипа находиться свойство `constructor` которое будет указывать на класс `Class` который создал это экземпляр.

Я бы хотел что бы вы мне пояснили на сколько правильно я понял эти два свойства.
Хотелось бы еще, что бы вы мне помогли понять смысл терминов, которые я привел выше из сайтов Мозили и Майкрософт, а то мне не очень понятно их трактовка.

Comment: _В первом пункте я не понял, что они подразумевают под словосочетанием ...создавшую прототип экземпляра._ - это ошибка в формулировке

Comment: Ошибка в русской версии MDN. В английской: _Returns a reference to the `Object` constructor function that created the instance object_ (Возвращает ссылку на конструктор Объекта который создал экземпляр объекта).

Comment: немного определений из [спецификации](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-constructor)

Comment: @Grundy я не владею английским, а на счет ошибку формулировки, вы имели ввиду определения взятое из сайта?

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, да, скорее _трудности перевода_

Answer (score -1):

изучаю сейчас тот вопрос, который ты поднял, ты наверное уже сейчас поднаторел в этом, но не могу не написать интересный код, который недавно нашёл.

```js
function Class(age){
  this.age=age
};

Class.prototype = Object.prototype; 

var best = new Class(25);

document.write((best.constructor===Class)+"<br>"); //false
document.write((best.constructor===Object)+"<br>"); //true
```

Из него получается, что это самое свойство `.constructor` на самом деле не является ссылкой именно на ту функцию(конструктор, "класс", как будет угодно), благодаря который и был создан экземпляр! То-есть, понимать ссылку `.constructor` как "с помощью неё был создан объект" - ошибка!?Просьба, никак не реагировать на данный ответ, не воспринимать его буквально, просто обычное наблюдение, чтобы не расписывать их в десяти отдельных комментах!